# Unable to catch error thrown inside a React component when testing with testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

**Component to test**

```
function ShopStatsConsumer({ shopId, shopName }) {
  return (
    <ShopStatsContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => {
        if (!(context || {}).state) {
          throw new Error('ERROR');
        }
        return <ShopStats context={context} shopId={shopId} shopName={shopName} />;
      }}
    </ShopStatsContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

**Testing with karma, testing-library**

```
it('throws error when not rendered inside a <ShopStatsProvider />', function () {
  const renderConsumer = () => {
    render(<ShopStatsConsumer {...props} />);
  };
  expect(renderConsumer).to.throw();
});
```

**Results**

> FAILED TESTS:   
> ✖ throws error when not rendered inside a 
> Chrome Headless 87.0.4272.0 (Mac OS 11.0.0)
> Error: Uncaught Error: ERROR ...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it cannot work this way as stated in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#how-about-trycatch) because `throws()` works like `try/catch` and can handle only imperative code.

In contrast, `<ShopStatsConsumer />` is imperative code...